# MS Access: How can I return all table and field names with in that table that have the field format 'hyperlink' via SQL or VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have multiple tables, within some of those tables I have fields that are formatted as hyperlink. I want to return the tables names that contain hyperlink formatted fields and the subsequent field names?

I am trying to do this within VBA, I'm thinking an SQL call within VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop through every `tableDef`/Table in the database, but it gets a little hairy since hyperlinks are an attribute on a `memo` field type. The `Attributes` property of Access objects are a bitmask, so when checking to see if a particular attribute is set, you have to check if that attributes bit is set in the bitmask.

```
Sub ListTablesWithHyperlinks()
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim tdfPrint As Boolean

    'Loop through all tables
    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        'Set flag to false
        tdfPrint = False

        'Loop through all fields
        For Each fld In tdf.Fields
            'Test if column has an attribute of `dbHyperlinkField`
            If (fld.Attributes And dbHyperlinkField) = dbHyperlinkField Then
                'Set the flag and exit the loop
                tdfPrint = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next fld

        'If the flag was set to true, then iterate fields again and print out
        If tdfPrint Then
            For Each fld In tdf.Fields
                'Print out tablename, column ordinal, and column name
                Debug.Print tdf.Name, fld.OrdinalPosition, fld.Name
            Next fld
        End If
    Next tdf
End Sub
```